# Customized User Location Annotation did not follow location update

Tags: iphone, objective-c, location

I implemented `MKMapViewDelegate` method below and customized user location annotation was displayed. However, the annotation did not move when I walked around with the iPhone. When I removed this delegate method, default the blue dot user location annotation followed me.

Please tell me how to move customized user location annotation:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"Annotation";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    if (!pinView)
    {
        pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];               
        pinView.animatesDrop = NO;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];

    return pinView;
}
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this I have the same problem it will not track my location using a custom annotation for the users location?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432746/custom-annotation-view-for-userlocation-not-moving-the-mapview