# UserLocation Image doesn't move

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I dont understand why the userLocation doesnt move when i set a costum image on it.

If i don't set an image, it uses the default pin blue and it works; i can see the userlocation moves when the postion changes.

here is my viewForAnnotation taken from an other post.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"Annotation";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mk dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    if (!pinView)
    {
        pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
        pinView.animatesDrop = NO;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    if (annotation == mk.userLocation)
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PositionPin.png"];
    else
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PositionPin.png"];

    return pinView;
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of 'mk'?

Comment: How about setting pinView.animatesDrop to YES?

Comment: no, pinView.animatesDrop is NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the map view (still present in iOS 6) where the user location coordinates no longer update when a custom annotation view is used (even though documentation suggests it will work).

A workaround is to use Core Location to get user location updates and create your own annotation (instead of using the map view's `userLocation`) and then supplying a custom image for it in `viewForAnnotation`.

See the answer to [Custom Annotation view for userlocation not moving the mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432746/custom-annotation-view-for-userlocation-not-moving-the-mapview/11435874#11435874) for more details and some sample code to implement the workaround.

In addition, note that when using a custom image for your annotation view, you should use `MKAnnotationView` instead of `MKPinAnnotationView`.
When using `MKPinAnnotationView`, it sometimes shows its default pin image instead of your custom image.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"Annotation";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mk dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    if (!pinView)
    {
        pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
        pinView.animatesDrop = NO;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PositionPin.png"];

    return pinView;
}
```

Comment: thx for your response but it's only move when i zoom on it, do you know why it doesn't move automatically ?