# MapView annotations not clickable and not showing details

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

1- I am using following code however my custom pins don't show bubbles like they should with Default my location pin.
2- Is there a way to customize my location pin to change color from default blue to red perhaps or increase its animation circle radius?

```
-(void) showMarkers
{
    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:[self.mapView annotations]];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 1;  i ++)
    {
        MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

        Players *player = [self.playersArray objectAtIndex:i];

        annotationPoint.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([player.latitude doubleValue], [player.longitude doubleValue]);
        annotationPoint.title = player.name;
        annotationPoint.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level %@", player.level ];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
        MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotationPoint.coordinate, 1500, 1500);
        MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
        [self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];

    }
}

- (void)map:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = userLocation.location.coordinate;
    myLocation = userLocation;
}

-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Current Location"] )
    {
        return nil;
    }

    MKAnnotationView *annView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"players"];
    annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker.png"];
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.enabled = YES;
    [annView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    return  annView;
}
```

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you see instead of the bubble?

Comment: nothing!! i click on my marker.png and nothing happens

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint and print the value of player, isn't that nil?

Comment: As Ramy suggests, check that player.name is not nil.  Is the map view's delegate set otherwise it won't call your viewForAnnotation.  Also, didUpdateUserLocation method should be named `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` (not `map:didUpdateUserLocation:`).

Comment: ain't nil, they markers are shown but they are not clickable or don't show popup

Comment: NSLog the player.name and see what it shows.  Also put a breakpoint on the canShowCallout=YES line and make sure it goes there.

Comment: got fixed, probably something was null i think subtitle. What about other , can we customize the default blue marker to animate on larger screen?

Comment: To customize the user location, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432746/custom-annotation-view-for-userlocation-not-moving-the-mapview for one approach.  There's no easy, built-in way to customize MKUserLocation directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently in an app, I have used custom image for showing bubble instead of default pin. The code used is posted below. Please have a look. Maybe it will help.

```
(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

Annotation *annotationInst = (Annotation*)annotation;


MKAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
if(annotation != mapView.userLocation)
{
    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"mypin";
    pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];

    if ( pinView == nil ){
        pinView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                   initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID]autorelease];

    }        

    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"];

    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton; 
}
else {
    [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"You are here"];
}
return pinView;
}
```

and for getting callout accessory button click:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{
Annotation *tappedAnnotation =  view.annotation;
CLLocationCoordinate2D tappedLocation = [tappedAnnotation coordinate];
```

}