# Custom icon for location.Possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

After much googling I'm nothing has come to my specific problem.

Is it possible to change the icon of the  blue location dot with the circle?
I would like to replace the locator icon with my own icon.

Then save it to a different view with my own image.By pressing a button.Like a Annotation.
The result would be the location in the "AddPlace"View should store the location in a different View.

I use the MapKit Framework.

Comment: can you explain more detail what do you need? 'localization' - may be 'location'?

Comment: Oh sorry, i mean the blue actual location Point.

Comment: on map? do you use MapKit?

Comment: Yes i use the MapKit.

Comment: try this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432746/custom-annotation-view-for-userlocation-not-moving-the-mapview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is delegate method of **MKMapView** - **viewForAnnotation**, which is called also for the location pin. When annotation is kind of class **MKUserLocation**

Example:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        MKAnnotationView *pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pinViewLocation"];
        if (!pinView) {
            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinViewLocation"];
            pinView.canShowCallout = NO;
            pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map-location-pin"];
        }
    }
    .....
```