# Swift MapKit custom current location marker

Tags: ios, swift, location, mapkit

This is what my `project` currently looks like. My questions is, how do I change the **blue ball** (current location) to a custom **image** or **icon**?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am sure you know that a user is used to seeing that blue-dot as the current user's location. You shouldn't change it unless you have a good reason.

Here is how to change it:

Set the delegate for the mapView, and then override the following function... something like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        let pin = mapView.view(for: annotation) as? MKPinAnnotationView ?? MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        pin.pinTintColor = UIColor.purple
        return pin

    } else {
        // handle other annotations

    }
    return nil
}
```

and to have an image displayed instead:
Just replace the code inside if statement with the following code:

```
let pin = mapView.view(for: annotation) as? MKPinAnnotationView ?? MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
pin.image = UIImage(named: "user_location_pin")
return pin
```

I think this code sample should give you enough information to help you figure out what to do. (Note that mapView is created in a storyboard...)

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let loc = CLLocationManager()
    var angle = 0
    var timer: NSTimer!
    var userPinView: MKAnnotationView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self
        loc.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.3, target: self, selector: #selector(rotateMe), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func rotateMe() {
        angle = angle + 10
        userPinView?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( CGFloat( (Double(angle) / 360.0) * M_PI ) )

    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            let pin = mapView.viewForAnnotation(annotation) ?? MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
            pin.image = UIImage(named: "userPinImage")
            userPinView = pin
            return pin

        } else {
            // handle other annotations

        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: True that, thanks alot for a clean and nicely done code. But is there someway I can change it from a pin to like a `icon`?

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! look [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2KwUi.png) btw, do you maybe know how to change the images heading regarding to the direction it is heading?

Answer (score 2):

You can customise the view using MKMapDelegate's method:

```
optional func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,
    viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
```

> **Parameters**
>
> *mapView* - The map view that requested the annotation view.
>
> *annotation* - The object representing the annotation that is about to be displayed. In addition to your custom annotations, this object
>   could be an MKUserLocation object representing the user’s current
>   location.

See full the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204-CH3-SW11)

Also please see the following SO question for updating the view when user location changes: 
[Custom Annotation view for userlocation not moving the mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432746/custom-annotation-view-for-userlocation-not-moving-the-mapview)